# Why does null.asInstanceOf[<some CPS annotated type>] fail?

Tags: scala, continuations, scala-2.10, continuation-passing

Is there any logical reason why `null.asInstanceOf[<some CPS annotated type>]` fails to compile?

For context, see [this github issue thread](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/29).

Comment: Are you sure it fails? for example null.asInstanceOf[Object @cps[String]] is compiled successfully (you can also replace Object/String with different types and it will works too).

Comment: @tzofia are you on 2.9.x? It fails for me on 2.10.

Comment: Hmm you are right.. works on 2.9 but fails on 2.10.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that we are using Scala 2.10.

Comment: `def fib(n: Int): Int @cps[Int] = { null.asInstanceOf[Int] }`    `reset { fib(0) } res40: Int = 0`    `reset { fib(1) } res41: Int = 0`

Comment: I wonder if it's time to report this as a 2.10 bug?

Comment: @PaulButcher, maybe you should do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the scala 2.9 version was doing the right thing even if it compiled (I'll try when I have a chance). Anyway, in 2.10.0 this compiles and works:

```
import scala.util.continuations._
object NullCPS extends App {
  def f[A,C] = shiftUnit[A,C,C](null.asInstanceOf[A])
  println(reset{"got " + f[Object, String]})  // prints: got null
  println(reset{"got " + f[Int, String]})     // got 0
  println(reset{"got " + f[Boolean, String]}) // got false   
}
```

`shitUnit[A,B,C]` is a library method from the [continuations package](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.continuations.package) that uses a value of type `A` to create a trivial `ControlContext[A,B,C]` expected to be used by a continuation k of type `A=>B` eventually returning a result of type `C`.

In my example above `"got " + f[Object, String]`, the continuation plugin further composes the trivial `null` value with the `(x:Object) => "got " + x` function.

Moving on to the [context of the question](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/scalamock/Defaultable.scala#L25), I cannot see how `Defaultable[T]` can represent the `T@cps[U]` since it only has one type parameter. But if you enhance `Defaultable`:

```
import scala.util.continuations._
trait DefCPS[A,C] { def default: A@cps[C] }
object NullCPS extends App {
  implicit def defaultCPS[A,C] = new DefCPS[A,C] {
    def default: A@cps[C] = shiftUnit[A,C,C](null.asInstanceOf[A])
  }
  println(reset{"got " + implicitly[DefCPS[Object,String]].default})
  println(reset{"got " + implicitly[DefCPS[Int,String]].default})
  println(reset{"got " + implicitly[DefCPS[Boolean,String]].default})
}
// prints got null
//        got 0
//        got false
```

Notes: I had to make the trait use a `def` instead of `val` or it would not compile. I also tried materializing a `A@cpsParam[B,C]` but was not able.